# Find if a number contains a digit without ever using using its string representation

Tags: code-golf, number

#### The Challenge:

Find if a number contains a digit. The number and the digit are to be taken as input. Output must be a boolean value. But you are not allowed to use the string representation of the number at any time. Now don't count upon a `char*` either. You must devise a mathematical way to do it.

**Rules:**

• You can't use a `string`/`char[]` representation of the number. Same goes for the digit.

• It must be a complete program.

• Input can be in any form.

• Output must be a boolean value.

*This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!*.

**Test Cases**:

```
Input: 51, 5
Output : True
------------------------
Input: 123456789, 0
Output : False
------------------------
Input: 1111, 1
Output : True
```

*Disclaimer*: *I don't understand much Pyth/CJam/Japt and similar languages. Thus I hope everyone will be honest enough not to break the rules. Never mind, the community is always there to help me :)*

Comment: Uh, isn't this just repeatedly mod then divide the number by 10? Unless you mean to include floating point, which isn't really clear from your test cases.

Comment: 05AB1E converts numbers to strings implicitly if needed. Is this also prohibited?

Comment: Also is built-in base conversion (from an integer to a list of digits) allowed?

Comment: @MartinBüttner no.

Comment: [Recommended reading.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/8478)

Comment: @MartinBüttner yep indeed. but completing the challenge without the restriction is so easy that... it's just..... you know what I mean..

Comment: What about `divmod`?

Comment: @Dennis what does that do? if it doesn't complete the job directly, then it's fine.

Comment: Do none of you understand "a complete program"?. That's there to maintain some uniformity.

Comment: `divmod(123, 10)` returns `(12, 3)`.

Comment: @Dennis No problem. Go ahead.

Comment: @FarhanAnam of course it's not interesting without the restriction, but that doesn't mean the restriction fixes that problem.

Comment: Some languages read all input as strings, regardless of whether the input is numeric. Are such languages then banned outright?

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 27 bytes

```perl6
{$^a.polymod(10 xx*)∋$^b}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# make it an infix op, because I can
my &infix:<contains> = {$^a.polymod(10 xx*)∋$^b}

say 51 contains 5; # True
say 123456789 contains 0; # False
say 1111 contains 1; # True

# you can use infix ops as oddly named subs as well
say infix:<contains> 1230, 0; # True

say map {$^a.polymod(10 xx*)∋$^b}, 10,0, 12,3, 12,2;
# (True False True)
```

```perl6
# proof it isn't doing anything string related
'hi' contains 'h';
# Method 'polymod' not found for invocant of class 'Str'
```

```perl6
# Since it uses a Set operator the second argument has to be an Int
# not a Str
say 123 contains '1'; # False
# not a Rat
say 123 contains 1.0; # False
# not a Num
say 123 contains 1e0; # False
# but an Int
say 123 contains 1; # True
```

#### Explanation:

`polymod` is similar to `divmod` from other languages, except it takes the number and a list of divisors. Here I give it an endless list of `10`s so that it splits it up into a list of digits.

Then I see if the resulting list contains the second argument by using the *'contains as member'* ( `∋` / `(cont)` ) Set operator.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

Called like `number!digitToFind`:

```
n!d|n<d=1>2|mod n 10==d=1<2|1<2=div n 10!d
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
t`10H#\t]xN$hm
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dGAxMEgjXHRdeE4kaG0&input=MTIzNDU2Nzg5CjA)

```
t                   % take 1st input (number) implicitly. Duplicate
 `      ]           % do...while loop
  10                % push number 10, to be used as divisor
    H#\             % divmod. Pushes remainder and then quotient
       t            % duplicate quotient. Used as loop condition: exit if zero
         x          % delete last quotient (which is zero)
          N$h       % concatenate all partial results in an array
             =      % take 2nd input (digit) implicitly.
              m     % ismember function. True if digit is in array
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> 47 bytes

```
in_array($d,array_map('intval',str_split($n)));
```

`$n` is the number to be searched
`$d` is the digit to search for

This code converts the `number` into `array[number]`, then scans the array for a matching digit.  Returns `true` if any digit matches.

Alternatively, if `number->string->array[string]->array[number]` is not valid (even though no operations use it *as* a string), there's this at **62 bytes**, for any `$n > 0`:

```
function f($n,$d){return$n&&($d==$n%10||f(($n-$n%10)/10,$d));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 59

It uses the same approach as every other approach.

```
def f(x,s):
 while x:
  x,r=divmod(x,10)
  if r==s:return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), 38 bytes

```
&&00pv >0.@.1<
%*25:<_^#:/_ ^#\*25-g00
```

Arguments are taken in the form `MainNum Digit`.  It's the same algorithm that everyone else is doing (check if mod 10 is equal to the digit; if not, div 10 until it equals 0), since that's pretty much the optimal way to do this one.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
d=>g=n=>n%10==d||n>9&&g(n/10|0)
```

Examples:

```
f=d=>g=n=>n%10==d||n>9&&g(n/10|0)
f(0)(0) -> true
f(0)(10) -> true
f(0)(12) -> false
f(1)(12) -> true
f(2)(12) -> true
f(3)(12) -> false
```